# How to map Multiple datasorce in spring-servlet.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I need to connect with multiple database using hibernate in my project. I tried using 2 datasource bean tag but its not working it throws error. But if I give 1 datasource bean it works fine. Here I show my properties file and servlet.xml file.

**database.properties:**

```
#mySQL DB Properties
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc
database.user=root
database.password=pass
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update


#DB2DB Properties
db2.driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
db2.url=jdbc:db2://123.141.74.323:50000/DB
db2.user=user
db2.password=pass
db2hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
db2hibernate.show_sql=true
db2hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

**spring-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!--Properties file  -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />

<!--Packages to scan  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gcs.*" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager1"/>

<!--View Resolver  -->

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!--End of View Resolver  -->

<!-- mySQL DataSource -->

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.gcs.beans.SystemBean</value>
                <value>com.gcs.beans.TemplateBean</value>
                <value>com.gcs.beans.LoginBean</value>
                <value>com.gcs.beans.TestSuitBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

<!-- End of mySQL DataSource -->

<!-- DB2 DataSource  -->    

    <bean id="DB2dataSource" class="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db2.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db2.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db2.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db2.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="DB2sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DB2dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.gcs.beans.AudTrailBean</value>
                <value>com.gcs.beans.AudTrailDtlBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db2hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db2hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db2hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>          
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager1"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="DB2sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

<!-- End of DB2 DataSource -->

<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

If I comment the second datasource bean means it works fine, but I didn't comment the second datasource bean means it throws error. Below I show the error.

**Error:**

```
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gcsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gcs.service.LoginService com.gcs.controller.GcsController.loginService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.gcs.dao.LoginDao com.gcs.service.LoginServiceImpl.loginDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.gcs.dao.LoginDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'DB2dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2DataSource]: Bean property 'driverClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't know where I made mistake. I hope anyone can help me to find the error.

Comment: you say "If I comment the second datasource bean means it works fine, but I didn't comment the second datasource bean means it throws error." So will it work if you change the name of the mySql datasource from 'dataSource' to say 'mySqlDataSource'... and update the sessionFactory as well?

Comment: @Atul asking me to change the name for datasource and sessionfactory for mysql source correct even then it throws the same error.

Comment: ..your ds configuration seems ok. I am not sure what the problem is. Is your DB2Driver jar downloaded from correct location? Also, if possible, try with com.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2XADataSource

Comment: @Atul actually that driver works fine in normal JDBC connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spring-servlet.xml looks fine. You are getting error when you are trying to inject sessionFactory. Please try the below code.

```
@Transactional(value ="hibernateTransactionManager",propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class FirstDao extends HibernateDaoSupport{


    @Autowired
    public void init(@Qualifier("sessionFactory1") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }


    public SampleEstimate fetchEstimate(long objectId){
        SampleEstimate estimate=(SampleEstimate) getSessionFactory().openSession().getNamedQuery("SampleEstimate.findOne").
                                setLong("objectId",objectId).list().get(0);
        return estimate;
    }

    public void saveGroup(SampleEstimateGroup group){
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(group);
    }

}
```

Second Session factory injection in another Dao

```
    @Transactional(value = "hibernateTransactionManager1",propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly = false)
public class SecondDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondSessionFactory")
    public void init(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory)   ;
    }

    public SecondDbEntity getSecondDbEntity(){
        return (SecondDbEntity)getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery("SecondDbEntity.findAll").get(0);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: can you please elaborate the HibernateDao class. Because am not experienced in this.

Comment: or if you have any good link have multiple database connections means please share it

Comment: can you tell me how you are injecting the session factor as you are only getting error while injecting the session factory

Comment: am just using @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

Comment: am not familiar with hibernate.cfg.xml so am using properties file only.

Comment: Let me add another code for Dao. I am creating differnt Dao for handling different sesison factories  and using @Qualifier to identify the sessionfactory. Don't worry about hibernate.cfg, without that also you will survive.

Comment: it is asking to create setSessionFactory method and propagation cannnot resolved to a variable. Did I want to add any jar??

Comment: now am getting No matching bean of type [com.gcs.dao.LoginDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=mySQLsessionFactory)}